# Prototype difference between object.create and new Object

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

```
//The last link of the prototype chain always be Object.prototype. 
var o = {"name":"kannanrbk", "age": 21};
//extending object.
var no = Object.create(o); //Now the new object is linked to the old object o. 
no.name = "Bharathi Kannan R";
console.log(o.name); //Still be 'kannanrbk'. Because, this prototype chain will be used only for retrieval.
//In js prototype is dynamic. If we add new property in this prototype. It will be visible immediately. 
o.sex = "Male";
console.log(no.sex);

//To find the property of the type 
console.log(typeof no.sex);

/**
* Enumeration
*/
for(var k in no) {
    console.log(no[k]);
}

//To check whether the property is belongs to the object.
console.log(no.hasOwnProperty('sex')); //false, it won't check the prototype chain.

var p = {"name":"kannanrbk","age":23};
var np = new Object(p);

//Why it returns true?
console.log(np.hasOwnProperty('age')); //true. 
np.age = 25;

//How the value is updated in entire prototype chain?
console.log(p.age);
```

What is the difference between Object.create and new Object(old)?

Comment: If `new Object` would be the same as `Object.create`, why would we need the latter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [MDN's documentation on `Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Description),

> The `Object` constructor creates an object wrapper for the given value. If the value is `null` or `undefined`, it will create and return an empty object, otherwise, it will return an object of a Type that corresponds to the given value. **If the value is an object already, it will return the value.**

The bold text is the key here. If you pass an object to `Object`, it will return the object as it is. That is why,

```
console.log(np.hasOwnProperty('age'));
```

return `true`. You can do one more check, like this

```
var p = {
    "name": "kannanrbk",
    "age": 23
};
var np = new Object(p);

console.log(np === p);
# true
```

because `np` and `p` are one and the same. Here, no prototype chain is established.

But, when you use `Object.create`, the parameter you pass to that will be used as the prototype of the object created, so the prototype chain will be established in that case. Quoting [`Object.create`'s MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Summary),

> The `Object.create()` method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.